# XAML Solution for Object height

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need a Solution for my Expander  Script in XAML.
It should be achieved that both expanders have always separated the same.

I have two expander, the lower Object need the Margin:
Upper Object.Margin.Top + Upper Object.Height + free space of 10 px

The upper Object heigh is expanded 140, and unexpanded 29.
The upper Object top margin is 18.

==> I need in the unexpanded state the result: 168px (140+18+10)
==> I need in the unexpanded state the result: 57px (29+18+10)

Comment: Are you using MVVM or code behind?  You can use XAML to bind the height of your controls to a variable in your DataContext, and you can use a button command to run a method that toggles between the two height values.  If you post what you have tried, I can be more specific...

Comment: Are you are using `Margin` to place your controls? I would highly recommend against that, and to use the correct Layout Panel instead. (I suggest [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30904/WPF-Layouts-A-Visual-Quick-Start) for a quick overview of Layouts if you're new to WPF). Sounds like a `StackPanel` would suit your purposes much better. That said, if you really want something like that I'd recommend a Converter. I have a [Math Converter on my blog](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/the-math-converter/) you can use if you want, or just create your own.